# how do i have a condition constantly checked, the second it becomes false, start a new task?

Tags: java, android, timer

So I am quite new on Java and currently im working on a small Timer for Android.
I have the problem that whenever I press the stop button and start the timer again, the task is getting executed from the beginning, for example:
if someone stops the timer at 00:50 (Sec:Ms) and starts it over again the second will take 1000ms and not 500ms.

```
int b = (100 - zaehler) * 10;


        while (b!=0)
        {
            time1.scheduleAtFixedRate(this.task1, 0, b);
            if (b==0) {
                this.task1.cancel();

            }
        }
```

"zaehler" is my ms count.
"b" is the time left in ms.
I want him to execute the task in given ms and it works, but the task is getting performed with the new given ms all the time for example 500ms. (1000ms is normal) so if a second passes and the ms start over from 0 I need a 1000 instead of the b.

Comment: Do you realise that `b` is not changing within your loop?

Comment: not at all, mind to explain?

Comment: He means you need to update b to current time left in while loop.

Comment: There are only 2 ways your code may execute:
if `b = (100 - zaehler) * 10 == 0` your loop will never execute at all.

Comment: if `b = (100 - zaehler) * 10 != 0` your loop will execute forever, the scheduler will schedule `task1` millions of times
and `task1` will never get cancelled.